# Vaadin 23: ScopeNotActiveException at MainView, that extends AppLayout View

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I have following Views structure:

Home Page

```
@SpringComponent
@UIScope
@PageTitle("ExampleApp: Home Page")
@Route(value = Endpoint.UI.HOME_PAGE, layout = MainView.class)
public class HomePage extends VerticalLayout {
  //the rest is ommited
}
```

few another pages like this and `MainView`:

```
@SpringComponent
@UIScope
@Push
@Viewport("width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes")
//@PWA - details ommited
@Theme(themeClass = Lumo.class, variant = Lumo.DARK)
@CssImport("./css/main_view.css")
public class MainView extends AppLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver, AppShellConfigurator {
   //implementation is ommited. 
}
```

In Vaadin `14.8.1` App works perfectly. But after updating to Vaadin `23.0.1` I got:

```
2022-03-14T09:39:07.191902382Z org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'mainView': 

Scope 'vaadin-ui' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton;

 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no UI available. The UI scope is not active
```

Question: how do I access UI Scope or Object from `MainView`?

Comment: It's at least weird that you have `@SpringComponent` in your MainView. Is there a reason for it? If you want to use `@Autowired` dependency injection in your MainView, it's enough that it is a RouterLayout (which comes from AppLayout)

Comment: There reason is: I have `PostConstruct` and `PreDestroy` annotated methods for registrering/unregistrering EventBus.